# Postgresql query finding rows in X and filtering after

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a table containing multiple Animal objects, the animals can be young or old. I am trying to create a query that finds animal names that don't have old animal_age. I need to check only specific animals
In the table we can have:
Dog - Young
Dog - Old
Cat - Young
Snake - Young
Snake - Old

I am trying to create a query that will find only Cat - Young. I was trying a query like:
select animal_name, animal_age from public.animals where animals_name in ('Dog', 'Cat')
but I need to somehow filter the results to get the animal names that have Young age and not Old. I am trying to find only Cat as there is no Cat-old

Comment: Hello. At the moment I can only guess that you mean the Cat in your data is "young" because it's lacking "old" adjective in the `animal_age` column. In that case, to get that Cat you'd `select animal_name, animal_age from public.animals where animal_name='Cat' and (animal_age is null or animal_age<>'Old');`

Comment: It's best to provide a sample of your data (paste the result of 'select * from public.animals limit 10;'), which row(s) from the table you are trying to get, and the exact query you're trying to use to get it. Right now it's not very clear: 1. I'm not sure what goes into `animal_age` (`Young` or `Young Dog` if the animal_name is `Dog`?), 2. why your query looks for Dogs as well if you just want a Cat, 3. whether the column is `animal_name` or `animals_name`, 4. what your sample is, because first you say you can have "Old Cat" in your data and later you claim "there is no Cat-old".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.